# Integration of SCORM with PHP/Yii

Tags: php, yii, scorm

Practically I am new to `SCORM` implementation in PHP.

Theoretically I covered these areas before asking a question here -

Already looked at [Wiki SCORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharable_Content_Object_Reference_Model) that what does it means theoretically.(kinda standard to be followed for delivering content).

Read about the moodle and SCORM(but may be I need to design my app in Yii, searched extensions but found none at repository).

Read most of the stuff at http://scorm.com/ and checked its PHP Library as well.

My concerns and queries -

I am familiar with PHP so how could I create an app that uploads an SCORM package, test it if its SCORM compliant and then can run the SCORM package. What are the things I need to keep in mind while creating such an app.

SCORM cloud looks good but it is costlier http://scorm.com/scorm-solved/scorm-cloud-features/ after 100MB so I am unable to use it for now.

Checked `chamilo SCORM` as well but it is another LMS.

Please provide me some example of implementation/github code/small app in php from which I can proceed further.

I know the solution is going to be little lengthy but believe me before asking I nearly checked all answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scorm and none looks beneficial.

FYI - I checked this as well https://cloud.scorm.com/ so what SCORM is clear to me but its link for its implementation in PHP in simple terms found no where.

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=SCORM+php&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults Seems like it have integration for php, and it's framework-independent. I dont know how else to help. I doubt you 'll found commercial projects open on github.

Comment: @ineersa thx for the response the link you mentioned doesn't contain any relevant info regarding open source project :(

Comment: Reason for down voting ??

Comment: "Please provide me some example of implementation/github code/small app in php from which I can proceed further" is not a real question. You're asking for someone to provide a solution, not answer a question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having built a SCORM player in PHP, here's what you need:

a) An importer, that reads XML from the imsmanifest.xml file and creates a representation in your system, if needed. The most important thing in this file is to find the "launch point" of the SCORM content

b) A SCORM engine, in javascript, that will communicate with the SCORM content

c) A database backend, to store what needs to be stored (based on the specification)

(b) above is the most important and difficult part, but it's also relatively easy to find as a complete piece of open source code (for example, [efront](https://github.com/epignosis/efront_open_source) contains an implementation, inside `www/js/LMSFuctions.php`)

Having said this and having supported SCORM content for years, I can tell you that implementing SCORM from scratch is difficult, but even more difficult is to make it work for all vendors, since there are many implementations each with its own tricky points. If you're doing this for a commercial audience, I would strongly suggest to go with a ready made implementation (scorm.com's is really great, but comes with all the drawbacks you've mentioned). Otherwise you may end up supporting it for much more time than you would want to (and was paid for).

Comment: Thx for the detailed explanation and sharing your thoughts..I am new to SCORM and very less content available on this topic(please update your answer in the meantime if you came across anything new that you would like to share +1)

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to build SCORM into your PHP system, have a second look at Chamilo, as well as Moodle. They are open-source, written in PHP, and contain everything you would need to 'bake' SCORM support into your system.

If you don't know what SCORM is or how it works, you need to read [the documentation](http://www.adlnet.gov/scorm/scorm-2004-4th).